# Collate production current number of inbound calls (year-to-date maximum and average at 5min intervals) per service per api

Tags: azure, rest, apim

I am looking to collate production current number of inbound calls (year-to-date maximum and average at 5min intervals) per service per API in Azure API management service.

Can someone help with the kusto query for this ?

I can retrieve the total number of calls using rest API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/reports/list-by-api?tabs=HTTP but how can we get the similar number for 5 min interval?

In order to rate limit on API requests and understand the current usage of total number of API calls per 5 minute interval.